# How do I switch between two iterators?

Tags: java, iterator

I have two different iterators created like this:

```
public class ColumnRowIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

private Integer[][] dataset;
private int rowIndex;
private int columnIndex;
private int index;

public ColumnRowIterator(Integer[][] dataset) {
    this.dataset = dataset;
}

public int currentRow(){
    return rowIndex;
}

public int currentColumn(){
    return columnIndex;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return rowIndex < dataset.length && columnIndex < dataset[rowIndex].length;
}

@Override
public Integer next() {
    if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    if(rowIndex == dataset.length-1){
        columnIndex++;
        rowIndex=0;
    }else {
        rowIndex++;
    }
    return dataset[(index % dataset.length)][(index++ / dataset.length)];

}

@Override
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

}
```

One moves first through columns and the other moves fist through the rows. Then I have another class called `Matrix` with different methods (like printing the matrix or changing some values). The constructor of the matrix is the following:

```
Matrix(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, boolean defaultRowColumnIterator) {
    if(rowIndex > 0 && columnIndex > 0) {
        this.matrix = new Integer[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
        this.index=0;
        this.defaultRowColumnIterator = defaultRowColumnIterator;
        for(int i = 0; i< rowIndex; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j< columnIndex; j++)
                this.matrix[i][j]=0;
    }
    else System.out.println("Los parámetros de la matriz no son válidos.");
}
```

`defaultRowColumnIterator` is a boolean and is what switches between the iterators. So is it possible to change the iterator so that the implementation in a method does not change. For example instead of writing ifs whith the 2 possibilities (`RowColumnIterator iterator = new RowColumnIterator(this.matrix);`) do it once like `Iterator iterator = new iterator(this.matrix);` or something similar.

```
public Integer[][] copyOfMatrix(){
    Integer[][] copy = new Integer[this.rowIndex][this.columnIndex];
    RowColumnIterator iterator = new RowColumnIterator(this.matrix);
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        copy[iterator.currentRow()][iterator.currentColumn()] = iterator.next();
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want access to the `currentRow()` and `currentColumn()` methods, you should create an interface with those.

I'd then recommend you create a helper method to instantiate the iterator.

```java
public interface MatrixIterator extends Iterator<Integer> {
    int currentRow();
    int currentColumn();
}
```

```java
public class Matrix {

    // fields, constructors, and other code

    private MatrixIterator matrixIterator() {
        return (this.defaultRowColumnIterator
                ? new RowColumnIterator(this.matrix)
                : new ColumnRowIterator(this.matrix));
    }

    private static final class ColumnRowIterator implements MatrixIterator {
        // implementation here
    }

    private static final class RowColumnIterator implements MatrixIterator {
        // implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Is there a way to de the new RowColumIterator(this.matrix) without this.matrix. Because I have a method that adds two matrix and I create two iterators, one with this.matrix and other with a matrix i pass to that method, matrix2

Comment: @SaúlLeyva I'm not sure I understand, but if you have a method `add(Matrix other)`, then you can call `new RowColumIterator(other.matrix)`.